# Database Select Query Confusion

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to keep all purchases from a single client together on a database table (It will be atored in my Orders table) and once someone is browsing a product, the system will search the dB for clients that bought that product and recommend the other products they bought (you will need to check for popularity of the other products and avoid repetition)

The data will be stored in a mysql database in a table called Orders. I then need to be able to search that database to see if other people have bought this product and if so which products they also bought.

So I've come up with this query

SELECT ProductName FROM  Orders

(I have little knowledge and would like to no if I am on the right track)

Answer (score 1):

> I need to keep all purchases from a single client together on a database table

For this one you probably need to create a horizontal view (restricting by the client id you need to monitor the purchases) [CREATE VIEW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html).

Could you provide your database schema ? in order to create the query you need you should join many tables, so it would be easier to provide the schema and how your tables are tied together.

Comment: e.g. each __order__ will contain clients details, totals etc.. Then __order_products__ will contain the order id from the __order__ table and the product details product_id, qty, price. One order many items

Comment: The order table will contain, orderId, OrderTotal, ProductName

Comment: @user2156135 does the order have many items ? do you have another table that associates the items (products) with the order ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
      SELECT ProductName
      FROM Orders WHERE client_id in
        (SELECT client_id
         FROM Orders 
         WHERE productname="ProductName ");
```

Comment: In order to bring more results back I need to create more select queries .